# How can I change the precision of a datetime2 for a system-versioned table (temporal table) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables, alter-column

I have 62 tables that were set up as system-versioned/temporal tables except the start and end time columns were set up as `datetime2(0)` as shown below.

```
SysStartTime [datetime2](0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
SysEndTime [datetime2](0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
```

Because of this, we have records within the history table that appear to be duplicated because we lose the necessary precision when records were modified multiple times by our system. I haven't been able to find any documentation on modifying those two columns, but tried the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE SystemVersionedTable 
    SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);

ALTER TABLE SystemVersionedTable 
    ALTER COLUMN SysStartTime DATETIME2(7);

ALTER TABLE SystemVersionedTable 
    ALTER COLUMN SysEndTime DATETIME2(7);

ALTER TABLE SystemVersionedTable 
    SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = History.dbo_SystemVersionedTable));
```

However, I still get the following error:

> Period column 'SysStartTime' in a system-versioned temporal table cannot be altered.

Is there a way to alter those two columns and set it to `datetime2(7)`?

Comment: You will need to create a new table

Answer (score 1):

The script below worked for me (of course you need to replace {tableSchema}, {tableName}, {historyTableSchema}, {historyTableName} with your values).

The script sets the new precision to 7 for SysStartTime and SysEndTime.

Note how the SysEndTime column needs to have the maximum DATETIME2 value for the given precision (hence the UPDATE).

Also note how the index ix_{historyTableName}, which is created by default when defining temporal tables, needs to be dropped and recreated.

See for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15#migrate-existing-tables-to-built-in-support

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    ALTER TABLE [{tableSchema}].[{tableName}] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)
    ALTER TABLE [{tableSchema}].[{tableName}] DROP PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME
    DROP INDEX [ix_{historyTableName}] ON [{historyTableSchema}].[{historyTableName}]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [{tableSchema}].[{tableName}]               ALTER COLUMN SysStartTime DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [{tableSchema}].[{tableName}]               ALTER COLUMN SysEndTime   DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [{historyTableSchema}].[{historyTableName}] ALTER COLUMN SysStartTime DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [{historyTableSchema}].[{historyTableName}] ALTER COLUMN SysEndTime   DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_{historyTableName}] ON [{historyTableSchema}].[{historyTableName}] (SysEndTime, SysStartTime)
    GO

    UPDATE [{tableSchema}].[{tableName}] SET SysEndTime = CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999')
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [{tableSchema}].[{tableName}] ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
    ALTER TABLE [{tableSchema}].[{tableName}] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [{historyTableSchema}].[{historyTableName}], DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON))
    GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```